# Can you replace a variable and its value in all open files in visual studio code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I was wondering if it is possible to replace all instances, in all open files of this construction time variable in visual studio code, they all have different number values after the colon. For ex. Replace all occurrences of "constructionTime":xxxxx, with "constructionTime":10,

[Construction time variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GW88.jpg)

Comment: Do not use images of code, please. See: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode (No, I didn't actually downvote!)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just post code image, otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE) that demonstrates your problem would help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is.

1. Open up the edit menu then select ***"Find and Replace"***.
2. After that select ***"Replace in Files"***. A small dialog should open.
3. Under ***"Find Options"*** select ***"use regular expressions"***
4. Select the ***"Look in"*** drop down, drop it open, so you can select ***"All Open Documents"***.
5. In the ***"Find what field"*** input, type: **`"constructionTime":*`** .    <--- space after *
6. In the Replace with field type: **`"constructionTime":10`** .
7. Then either hit Find Next and Replace on instances you wish to replace or
   hit replace all.

The **`*`** is the Regular Expression Wild-Card character, and it will "find" anything it atches, that comes after it. Typically you would want to place another character after the Wild-Card, that way the search is limited, however; in your case I chose a space, but in you case you might have to try with , ; ) and the like.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've gotten that for on my own, the problem I have run into is that each instance of constructionTime is followed by a random number with 1 to 5 digits example - "constructionTime":18000, or "constructionTime":120,

Comment: ah, sorry about that, hit the post a little to soon, you can use the wild card character if you select use regular expressions, might help. I edited the above to show.

Comment: Having a space "," or other characters after * didn't find anything, without the space it found all occurences, but when I replace them I wind up with not replacing the value, but just adding more to it example- "constructionTime":18000, turned into "constructionTime":10 18000,

Comment: For a regular expression search, you might start with something like `"constructionTime":\d+`  And maybe augment it later to handle spaces if necessary.

Comment: That worked perfect Wyck, thanks to both of you. It ended up adding an extra blank line under each instance of constructiontime, but that seems to not be causing any errors so I'm happy with that for now :)

Comment: I personally wouldn't use a regular expression feature to achieve this. It can be done with a simple Hot-Key, CTRL+D (recursive selection), CTRL+L(Select all words), CTRL+F2(select all of what is selected),  & CTRL+F (select all search results)